# Extract Keys/Values from Dictionary and Store as Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where one column contains a list of dictionaries with the same keys:

```
[{'name': 'Order Type', 'value': 'traditional'}, {'name': 'Delivery Window', 'value': '8 - 10'}, {'name': 'Delivery Day', 'value': 'Saturday'}]
```

I'd like to extract the value of the name key as a column in my dataframe and the value of the value key as the record in that column.  The possible distinct values of the name key is unknown so if there's a way to do this dynamically that would be ideal.  Output given this particular row would be:

[image]

To emphasize the input isn't a raw list, it's a list that is in a dataframe column.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd



data = {
    "foo": [1],
    "spam": [2],
    "data": [[{'name': 'Order Type', 'value': 'traditional'}, {'name': 'Delivery Window', 'value': '8 - 10'}, {'name': 'Delivery Day', 'value': 'Saturday'}]]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(f"{df}\n")

   foo  spam                                                                                                 data
0    1     2  [{'name': 'Order Type', 'value': 'traditional'}, {'name': 'Delivery Window', 'value': '8 - 10'},...

df2 = pd.json_normalize(df["data"]).transpose().rename(columns={0: "data"})
df2 = pd.concat([df2.drop("data", axis=1), pd.DataFrame(df2["data"].tolist())], axis=1).transpose()
df2 = df2.rename(columns=df2.iloc[0]).drop(df2.index[0]).reset_index(drop=True)
print(f"{df2}\n")

    Order Type Delivery Window Delivery Day
0  traditional          8 - 10     Saturday

df_final = pd.merge(df.drop("data", axis=1), df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
print(df_final)

   foo  spam   Order Type Delivery Window Delivery Day
0    1     2  traditional          8 - 10     Saturday
```